# Scrolling on a number picker using robotium

Tags: android, testing

Can anyone suggest me how to scroll over a number picker in order to change the number to be selected using `robotium`?
I came across the following but I can't figure out how to use it `scrollBy(x,y)`.
I used the following but it didn't seem to work.

```
solo.getView(R.id.numberPicker1).scrollBy(0,100);
```